# How do I replace all lines after line XX in one file with content from another file?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm on Debian 8.2. Here's `test.sh` so far.

```
#!/bin/bash
wget http://winhelp2002.mvps.org/hosts.txt -O fileA
tail -n +26 fileA >> fileB
```

I want lines 26 onwards of `fileA`'s content to replace everything in `fileB` from line 26 onward — so I end up with the first 25 lines of the output are from lines 1-25 of the original `fileB` and the remainder is lines 26 onwards of `fileA`.

How do I do this?

Comment: The most obvious way is `cat <(head -n 25 fileB) <(tail -n +26 fileA)`, but you can't directly write the output to `fileB`; you either need to write to a tempfile first, or use something like `sponge`. Alternatively, you can write a `sed` one-liner if you're cunning: `bash -c 'sed -i -n "1,25p; 26 r "$1 fileB' -- <(tail -n +26 fileA)`. Maybe there are more obvious one-liners that I don't see.

Comment: i would just use curl to reduce the need for temp files

Comment: @ReubenL. I'm new to shell. What's the difference in output produced by `wget` vs `curl`?

Comment: @ReubenL. `wget` can write to stdout as well. Just `wget -qO -`.

Comment: @4ae1e1 `curl -s` is shorter =P

Comment: @ReubenL. `curl` doesn't handle redirects by default (need `-L`). `wget` handles redirects out of box, so it is more beginner-friendly.

Comment: @4ae1e1 That's crazy. `wget` has a number of problematic default behaviors which are hostile to beginners and advanced users alike.

Comment: @Username: In future, please add crucial clarifying information to the question, as I just did (or somewhat like that – edit it if you don't like what I said) and do not add it as a comment.  Thanks.

Comment: @tripleee Like? Off the top of my head I can only think of wget's possible HTTPS certificate problem, which is easy to work around. And speaking of wget's strengths as just a downloader, there are plenty: default to file with remote name, handle redirects by default, easier and saner logging, etc. I consider myself a relatively advanced user of `wget` (been using it for years in various settings), and I've yet to see how it's hostile. Of course you're entitled to your own opinions, but speaking for "beginners and advanced users alike" without some solid evidence or citation is unconvincing.

Comment: @Username By the way, sorry for vandalizing your post...

Comment: @4ae1e1 I particularly recall trying to mirror a bunch of sites without having to hard-code a separate `wget` command line for each in order to decide where on disk I wanted the files to end up.  It's basically impossible to wrestle out of the `www.example.com/path/to/dir` straitjacket `wget` enforces.

Comment: @tripleee Okay sure, I may agree with you that this is not as customizable as it could be, but what's so hard about postprocessing (a single `mv` call)? And is recursive download the use case of a typical beginner, or that of all/most advanced users? Most importantly, is `curl` even an option in your case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
wget http://winhelp2002.mvps.org/hosts.txt -O fileA
head -25 fileB > tempfile && mv tempfile fileB
tail -n +26 fileA >> fileB
```

`head -25` will take first 25 lines from fileB and dump it to tempfile. Then tempfile will be renamed to fileB.

Comment: `sed -i -n '1,25p' fileB` would avoid the tempfile.

Answer (score 4):

If you want the whole of `fileA`, you could use:

```
sed -i.bak -e '26r fileA' -e '26,$d' fileB
```

This reads the contents of `fileA` into the output after reading line 26 (but before printing or otherwise processing it); it then deletes lines 26 to the end of `fileB`.  The `-i.bak` option means that `fileB` is overwritten with the output of the command (but a backup copy is made with suffix `.bak`).  Different versions of `sed` handle 'no backup' with `-i` differently; this will work with both (all?) of them.  If you use GNU `sed`, `-i` on its own is sufficient; if you use Mac OS X (BSD) `sed`, you need `-i ''` to specify it.

---

The question has been clarified so it requires lines 1-25 of the original `fileB` and lines 26-EOF of the original `fileA` in the output file `fileB`.  This is a tad fiddly, not least because [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution) only works outside quotes.  On systems where `/dev/stdin` is available (most Unix-like systems), you could use:

```
 sed 1,25d fileA | sed -i.bak -e '26r /dev/stdin' -e '26,$d' fileB
```

The first `sed` command deletes lines 1-25 of `fileA` and writes the result (lines 26-EOF) to its standard output, which is the standard input of the second `sed` command.  The second `sed` command reads the file from `/dev/stdin` when it reaches line 26 of `fileB`, and then deletes lines 26-EOF of `fileB`, with overwriting as before.

<sup>*NB: A previous version of this answer used `25r` instead of `26r`; this was an off-by-one error that's now fixed.*</sup>